# Should one pray after 'Asr?

Tags: salat, hadith-interpretation

There appears to be two different hadiths on praying after 'Asr.

Some hadiths say it is haram.

> Narrated Abu Sa'id Al-Khudri: I heard Allah's Apostle saying, "There is no prayer after the morning prayer till the sun rises, and there is no prayer after the Asr prayer till the sun sets." ([Bukhari Volume 1, Book 10, Number 560](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/9/62))
>
> Allah's Apostle forbade the offering of two prayers:
>   1. after the morning prayer till the sunrises.
>   2. after the 'Asr prayer till the sun sets. ([Bukhari Volume 1, Book 10, Number 562](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/9/64))

Some hadiths say it is highly encouraged.

> 'Aisha (addressing me) said, "O son of my sister! The Prophet never missed two prostrations (i.e. Rakat) after the 'Asr prayer in my house." ([Volume 1, Book 10, Number 565](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/9/67))
>
> Allah's Apostle never missed two Rakat before the Fajr prayer and after the Asr prayer openly and secretly. ([Bukhari Volume 1, Book 10, Number 566](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/9/68))
>
> Whenever the Prophet come to me after the 'Asr prayer, he always prayed two Rakat. ([Bukhari Volume 1, Book 10, Number 567](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/9/69))

Am I misunderstanding this? Is it allowed/encouraged to pray after 'Asr?

Comment: I unfortunately have no time to answer but a part of the answer is that scholars of the shafi'i madhab indeed use these ahadith as a proof for praying sunnah after 'asr, while others say the Prophet pbuh has prayed qaza' of nafl prayers.

Answer (score 1):

Scholars , like Imam Nawawi , said in [Sharh Sahih Muslim, Volume:6  Pages:110,121](http://ia902303.us.archive.org/35/items/alhelawy05/shsm06.pdf) , that it's Makruh , not haram. Makruh means: undesirable/disapproved .

he said it is the ijma' (consensus) of the Umma (Muslim community) that it's Makruh to pray for no reason during those mentioned times , but it is acceptable  to pray 'missed Nafila' (additional prayer missed) at those times .

he also mentioned that there are scholars that say it is a 'unique characteristic' (plural: Khasa'is) for the prophet only. 
I found that Ibn Hajar al-'Asqalani mentioned it in [Fath al-Bari](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=1105&idto=1111&bk_no=52&ID=385) as it is said by scholars who say it's always Makruh:

> and who said it's Makruh whatsoever, answered that his action [the prophet's] implies that it is acceptable to pray the missed Rawateb (extra prayers) without it being Makruh.

and he also referred  to Al-baihaki:

> Al-baihaki said: "what is a unique characteristic for the prophet peace be upon him, is the continuity, not the making up itself  [for missed prayers]  "

and he mentioned this narration:

> as Narrated by Aisha, Ummul Mu'minin:
>   Dhakwan, the client of Aisha, reported on the authority of Aisha: "The Apostle of Allah (peace be upon him) used to pray after the afternoon prayer but prohibited others from it... " [[Sunan Abu dawud, Book 4, Number 1275]](http://www.islam4theworld.net/hadith/abu_Daud/SUNAN%20ABU-DAWUD,%20BOOK%204%20Prayer%20(Kitab%20Al-Salat)%20Detailed%20Rules%20of%20Law%20about%20the%20Prayer%20during%20Journey.htm)

Wa Allah-u A'alm 
(and God is the most knowing).